How to connect MySQL Workbench to an AWS EC2 instance
To be a bit more specific, I am currently running a Django project on an Ubuntu EC2 instance in AWS. So far, there hasn't been much of an issue starting the server there. In the case of the MySQL workbench, I also managed to connect it to my Django project but only locally through my Visual Studio Code editor. Because of that, I've been trying to find a way on connecting the MySQL workbench app to my Django object on an AWS EC2 instance.
Just in case, I installed mysql-server and created a user to establish a new MySQL connection. However, I had to do it in an unsafe way, which is updating the mysqld.cnf file and changing the bind-address and mysqlx-bind-address to 0.0.0.0, as show here. 
For my settings.py file, I added this for the DB connection:
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'db_schema_name',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'IPv4_of_my_instance',
    'PORT': '3306'
}

I also added an inbound rule to my EC2 instance to allow MySQL/Aurora access from any address. After some time, I managed to connect the ubuntu instance in AWS to the newly created MySQL connection. However, since I know this was an unsafe way of doing it, I tried doing the other way, which is going with SSH. This is what is shown for me: 
Even as I entered all the necessary information there, it gives me an error that I failed to connect to it, and I want to fix this issue. I'm not sure if maybe it has to do with the SSH Key File, which I tried to create it from the Network and Security section, giving it an RSA key type and .pem format. This is my first time doing this so I hope this clears up my problem a bit more.

The correct and secure way to do this would be through an SSH tunnel. This means that you will instruct MySQL workbench to open an SSH connection to the AWS Ubuntu instance and use that connection to connect to the MySQL running instance.
Open the MySQL Workbench software on your device and setup a new connection, you should see a screen like this:

Input your connection name, for example (Remote DB), and under the connection method dropdown list choose (Standard TCP/IP over SSH), you will see the following screen:


Under the hostname field, enter the public IP address of your AWS instance (usually called "Elastic IP"), and if you're using a different port than 22 for your SSH connections then add a colon after the hostname followed by the number of your SSH port.
Under the SSH username field, enter the username you use to SSH into your instance.
Leave the SSH password field empty, because you don't use passwords to SSH into the AWS instance.
In the SSH key file field, enter the path to your private key file that you use to SSH into the instance, this is usually a PEM file.
Unless you're using AWS RDS, leave the MySQL hostname field as is without change.
Unless you have changed the default port that MySQL uses, leave the MySQL server port field as is without change.
In the username field, enter the username you use to connect to MySQL.
In the password field, enter the password you use to connect to MySQL.
Optionally, you may select a default schema that may be displayed upon opening MySQL workbench, but you can leave it empty for now.

Click the (Test Connection) button, MySQL workbench may freeze for a few seconds while testing the connection, but if all goes well you should see a success message such as:


There's also a less-secure way which I highly discourage because of the security concerns associated with it, but I'm going to mention it here anyway.
You can configure your MySQL instance to connect to be accessible publicly, this can be done by changing the bind-address configuration variable and setting it to 0.0.0.0, then you will need to adjust the firewall of your Ubuntu instance to allow inbound/outbound traffic on port 3306 (or whatever port you use for MySQL), here I'm talking about a software like ufw (in case you have it installed).
But that's not all, you still need to go to your EC2 security group page and configure the firewall there to allow inbound/outboun traffic on the same port.
Once again, I strongly advise against using this approach.

I edited my question in more detail. Unfortunately, I had to go with the latter option just in case. It worked so far, but just as you said, it's very unsafe. My problem is I really did try to go for the first option, but I kept getting an error when trying to test for connection. This is even after I updated the mysqld.cnf file to make the bind-addresses no longer be set to 0.0.0.0 (changing it bach to 127.0.0.1).  Maybe it's because I forgot to restart the MySQL server, or probably is my SSH Key File, but i'm not too sure.

@JSNew134 Okay, but be careful and use a very strong password, and preferably when you release the project to production restore all settings to their original state.

I have an update, sorry if it took me this long to reply. I managed to do the safer option you suggested. All I had to do was to launch another instance but this time paired with the generated private key. It took me a while but it managed to connect just fine, so thanks a lot for your help!

@JSNew134 I'm glad it worked for you in the end, and you're more than welcome !
